# Double donut/Multilayer Donut chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I need a double Donut chart in power BI. Custom visual in power bi or Deneb(vegalite) solution needed. I have data like this

| Year | Category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Category 1 | 25 |
| 2021 | Category 2 | 50 |
| 2021 | Category 3 | 25 |
| 2022 | Category 1 | 50 |
| 2022 | Category 2 | 25 |
| 2022 | Category 3 | 25 |

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV04e.png)
the expected output in power bi I needed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - this isn't a coding service. Ask your question with research shown, code tried etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time at least have a test in vega editor and let us know where you've had troubles. Here is an example that will get you started..

In your example your donut sections did not start at "midnight". This is always good to do as it is much easier for the user to see how large the donut sections are just like reading the time (00:15, 00:30 etc).

- Edit: Made year dynamic based on min and max year transforms.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple donut chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"year": 2022, "category": 1, "value": 10},
      {"year": 2022, "category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"year": 2022, "category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"year": 2023, "category": 1, "value": 8},
      {"year": 2023, "category": 2, "value": 20},
      {"year": 2023, "category": 3, "value": 10}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "window": [{"op": "sum", "field": "value", "as": "year_total"}],
      "frame": [null, null],
      "groupby": ["year"]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.value / datum.year_total * 100",
      "as": "percent_of_year_total"
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "min", "field": "category", "as": "Yeartext"}],
      "groupby": ["year"]
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "min", "field": "year", "as": "minYear"}],
      "groupby": []
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "max", "field": "year", "as": "maxYear"}],
      "groupby": []
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "year", "title": "Year"},
      {"field": "value", "title": "Value"},
      {"field": "percent_of_year_total", "title": "Value %", "format": ".2f"}
    ],
    "theta": {"field": "percent_of_year_total", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "category",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"range": "category"}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.year == datum.maxYear"}],
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "innerRadius": 80, "radius": 100}
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.year == datum.maxYear"},
        {"filter": "datum.category == datum.Yeartext"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"value": "black"},
        "text": {"field": "year"},
        "x": {"value": 100},
        "y": {"value": -10}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.year == datum.minYear"}],
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "innerRadius": 59, "radius": 79}
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.year == datum.minYear"},
        {"filter": "datum.category == datum.Yeartext"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": null,
        "color": {"value": "black"},
        "text": {"field": "year"},
        "x": {"value": 100},
        "y": {"value": 55}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: In the question I asked, the pic is just for reference. I know it starts at "Midnight". Sorry for the confusion caused.
To explain where I exactly facing problem is :
1) For every layer you're using transform to filter particular year data then you plotting the chart. If I get next year data(2024), then I need to change the code again. Is there any way?

Comment: Yes - if you have just 2 years then create a calculate transform to get the min and max years. Please mark the case as solved.

Comment: @UdayGRaikar I have updated the answer now. Please mark as solved.